# Best way to use API with Angular Async

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework

I want to use my API asynchronously. I get some data from my API and i need to display them.

Here an example :

**home.ts**

```
async ngOnInit()
{
    console.log("NgInit 01");
    this.data = await this.api.getMe();
    console.log("NgInit 02");
    this.canDisplayData = true;
}
```

**home.html**

```
<div *ngif="canDisplayData">
   myData : {{ data }}
</div>
```

**service_api.ts**

```
async getMe() {
    let result: any;

    await this.http.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => { result = res; })
        .catch(error => { console.log(error); });

    return result;
  }
```

this works, but i'm not proud at all of it. I'm sure i can do something better. Without use `async` and `await`.

Thank you for teaching me life, *of angular/ionic* :D

Comment: Try using observable / subscribe

Answer (score 1):

async/awit work on promise only so you need to convert observable to promise

*service_api.ts*

```
getMe() {
    return this.http.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
  }
```

*home.ts*

```
async ngOnInit()
{
    console.log("NgInit 01");
    this.data = await this.api.getMe().toPromise();
    console.log("NgInit 02");
    this.canDisplayData = true;
}
```

another way is to use async pipe

async/awit work on promise only so you need to convert observable to promise

*service_api.ts*

```
getMe() {
    return this.http.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees');
  }
```

*home.ts*

```
ngOnInit()
{
    console.log("NgInit 01");
    this.data$ = this.api.getMe();
    console.log("NgInit 02");
}
```

tenplate

```
<div >
   myData : {{ data$ | async}}
</div>
```

Comment: super minor note, I wouldn't call it this.data anymore but more like this.dataPromise. You probably would do the same but people who read this would probably need to take note. (I didn't downvote before)

Comment: @misha130 I don't get your point is there any wrong with my answer so I can edit

Comment: this.dataPromise = this.api.getMe();
    {{ dataPromise | async }}  <- I meant like this, because its no longer the data but rather the promise of the data

Comment: I'd recommend learning the power of observables instead of converting to promises.

Comment: @ShamPooSham I never use toPromise becuase I don't use async/awit  

Comment: @ShamPooSham check my answer async pipe section

Comment: Your async pipe section is better IMO, but you forgot to put a `return` in the `getMe()`

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't recommend to use async and await with angular when we have observable and subscribe of rxJs, just convert your code like this save extra variables too -

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getMe()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

<div>
   myData : {{ data }}
</div>

getMe() {    
    return this.http.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
      .map(res => {
        return res;
      });
  }
```

Comment: 1) `let result: any` in `getMe()` isn't needed anymore. 2) In Angular 6+, you need to use `pipe` on the observable and use the operator `map` inside of it.

Comment: Well, even if you are recommending it you have to mention the memory leaks of just using a subscribe without unsubscribe

Comment: @ShamPooSham my bad, forgot to remove extra code, also I didn't understand you second point, can you edit my answer? or explain bit more.

Comment: @misha130 HttpClient will complete itself, no need to unsubscribe.

Comment: @misha130 totally agree with your point, As I replicate only question part so forogot to add unsubscribe, also I answered assuming OP is using httpModule not httpClient.

Comment: @PardeepJain You're using the old rxjs syntax, take a look at the examples here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html

Comment: @ShamPooSham he is actually using Ionic 3(from tags) so most likely he is still on rxjs5 and still using the old syntax and honestly its just a good point to know that you sometimes need to unsubscribe when using observable even if he is in this case maybe using HttpClient

Comment: @misha130 That's true, I'm not familiar with ionic. Sure, it's not a bad point

Comment: Yep sry i forget to tell you that i use ionic4 beta and HttpClientModule ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with below one, async and await can slow your app.

**Home.ts**

```
 ngOnInit()
        {
            this.api.getMe().subscribe((data)=>{
               this.canDisplayData = true;
               this.data = data;
            }, (err) => {
               console.log(err);
            });
        }
```

**Home.html**

```
<div *ngif="canDisplayData">
   myData : {{ data }}
</div>
```

**service_api.ts**

```
getMe() {
    return this.http.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees');
  }
```